# Passing Multiple Between Statements To Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table full of products, previously we passed a `MaxPrice` and `MinPrice` to the stored procedure and selected products with the price between two values.

But now I want to pass multiple range values and want to select products that their prices are between multiple ranges.

Let's say I had a stored procedure like this:

```
@PriceMin decimal(18, 4) = null,
@PriceMax decimal(18, 4) = null,

... 
WHERE 
    product.Price > @PriceMin 
    AND product.Price < @PriceMax
```

but now I want to pass multiple range of values based on user selection and have a select like this:

```
WHERE 
    (product.Price > @PriceMin1 AND product.Price < @PriceMax1)
    OR (product.Price > @PriceMin2 AND product.Price < @PriceMax2)
    OR (product.Price > @PriceMin3 AND product.Price < @PriceMax3)
...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: use dynamic query to construct WHERE clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume that you don't know how many ranges are going to be passed up front, so I'd take up table value parameter to pass data to the stored procedure.

**Step 1:** Create a TVP

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Ranges AS TABLE  
    ( PriceMin  decimal(18, 4), PriceMax   decimal(18, 4) )
```

**Step 2:** Modify your stored procedure parameter list and code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_selectBasedOnPrice   
    (@rangeList dbo.Ranges READONLY)  
BEGIN
..
-- from product
-- WHERE product.Price > @PriceMin and product.Price < @PriceMax

from product p JOIN @rangeList r
 on p.Price  BETWEEN r.PriceMin  AND r.PriceMax 
END
```

PS: Note that `BETWEEN` is better than `>` and `<` statement,in this case if your price ranges are inclusive i.e. if you actually need <= and >=; and `JOIN` is much better than multiple `WHERE` clauses

Please do note that BETWEEN is equivalent to short hand for <= , >= and not <, >

<kbd>[MS documentation on TVP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)</kbd>

Comment: Why is `BETWEEN` better than `>` and `<` (other than the fact that the two are not equivalent)?

Comment: I agree they are not same, in fact many times I've been in a soup due to wrong use of `BETWEEN` (especially with datetime arguments). I wanted to tell OP to use between rather than <, > because (I guessed that) this problem actually should be using BETWEEN (i.e. inclusive on the ranges) and BETWEEN is just sweet and clear syntax.